# Are the user rss feeds not available any longer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed

I just realised that the RSS icon in firefox disappeared and my feed in Google Reader does not display an update made today.

Is it

1. just a bug?
2. a feature that has disappeared intentionally with the last update?
3. that I have a problem seeing orange coloured items?

I hope for (1)

Kay

[Update:] Google Reader and thus the news section of my web site via feedburner now has got my recent posting - the most important part for me. Still no RSS icon

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/353700/why-doesnt-firefox-show-any-kind-of-a-feed-presence-indication-when-there-is-ar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We missed the link on the new user profile - it will be in the next build.