# One's own profile no longer shows RSS feed for responses?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, feed, responses

The lower right corner of one's own "Responses" tab [used to show](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90772/how-to-keep-track-of-questions-im-answering/90784#90784) an icon that linked to an RSS feed for *"the 30 latest comments, answers, and revisions to a user's content"*. For profiles of others it was not shown, but [nevertheless available manually](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/84237/responses).

The latter still works, but I can no longer find the icon and its link.

I'm tagging this as bug as I assume it was lost in action when the new user profile was introduced in November 2011, just like `<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" ...>` was [lost shortly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113871/are-the-user-rss-feeds-not-available-any-longer/113903#113903). But maybe it was removed on purpose, or moved to a place I didn't look?

As an aside, I know [Jeff stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62588/rss-overhaul-desperately-needed/104673#104673):

> To be brutally honest, we are moving away from RSS to more email and web-based solutions to some of these things these days -- like [newsletter subscriptions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/stack-exchange-site-newsletters/) and [tag subscriptions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/).
>
> To be clear, RSS is still there, and it's not going away any time soon [...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are likely re-working *some* part of the profile to make room, we'll update more on that later...but it may or may not end up being responses, so we went ahead and gave it no special behavior (e.g. an RSS footer) intentionally since it may be removed later.

The feed is still available directly, that's intentional.

Comment: As an aside, I assume you know: just having an RSS link in the HTML makes some browsers show an RSS icon too. Such link is currently present in anyone's user profile, just like on many other pages. (I am not sure if the link ever disappeared from the HTML? Chrome doesn't show such RSS icon, [but Safari does](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MntxU.png).) However, the responses page defines the very same link as the other profile pages, hence: being the regular user's activity feed, not the user's responses feed: `<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="..." href="/feeds/user/84237">`.

Comment: You can easily get a Chrome extension that detects RSS / Atom feeds in a page and inserts an icon in the Omnibox.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but hiding such a useful feature seems like complete nonsense to me. Is there any official way of getting rss feed of user's responses?