# How can I see deleted comments on my question?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

In my notification bar at the top of the page, there's a pretty rude comment about my question, but when I try to look at it, it's already been deleted. I'd really like to be able to respond to that comment (in a polite, professional manner, of course.) Is there any way I can see comments that have been deleted?

Comment: As an aside: to archive and to easily search your own posts and responses, you could set up a RSS reader, [though responses are a bit hidden nowadays](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118242/ones-own-profile-no-longer-shows-rss-feed-for-responses). And then configure that reader to keep content forever. Of course, the chance that the reader happens to fetch a comment that is deleted soon after it was posted is still small though. (Your SO responses [are here](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/341611/responses), and your own activity [here](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/341611).)

Answer (score 16):

No, there isn't. Moderators can see deleted comments, but regular users cannot.

Since the comment was deleted, I don't think there's any need to respond to it either. I would just let it go. No good can come from responding to someone who's just being rude, no matter how polite and professional you are in response.

Look on the bright side - the system works and the rude comment wasn't allowed to persist on the site.

Answer (score -1):

You need to become a moderator in order to see deleted comments.

Comment: @Diago There is no other type of moderator other than a diamond moderator.  Non-moderators can moderate the site to a degree, but they still aren't moderators.